# Time conversion issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to convert this date format `Jun 8, 2017, 2:04 PM` in Oracle DB to `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS`. When I use the below query

```
select lst_upd_tstmp,
       to_char(lst_upd_tstmp, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') 
  from Timetable
```

I get 2 hrs and 30 min difference.

Output for Above query:

```
06/08/2017 04:34:27
```

Actual date in DB:

```
Jun 8, 2017, 2:04 PM
```

Comment: Timezone issue?

Comment: Not related to the 2h30 time difference but `HH` is a 12-hour clock; you want `HH24` for a 24-hour clock format model.

Comment: What is the column data type? And what does `dump(lst_upd_tstmp, 16)` return for that value?

Comment: Also, where are you running the query - directly in a client (if so, which one) or from an application? It may be a time zone discrepancy between your application (automatically converting a date/timestamp to local time, but not touching a string obviously) and the database session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

select lst_upd_tstmp,
   to_char(lst_upd_tstmp, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') 
from Timetable;
```

Comment: The string format for the date/timestamp value is being specified by the second argument to`to_char()` for the second column. This will only affect how the implicit conversion of the first column is displayed - *if* this is being run in a client that honours that. How does it explain the apparent time difference?

Comment: @AlexPoole - one available action for clearly unuseful answers is a downvote.